# How to emulate iOS style dropdown menus with html, css, javascript/jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, web-applications

[image]

The lower portion of that image contains the element I'm seeking to emulate. My job is to recreate a native iOS app as a multiplatform mobile webapp with PhoneGap, and the supervisor wants it to look EXACTLY like the old version. So I need to make an ordinary html dropdown menu appear as that lottery-machine style rolling cylinder of options. Anyone know a trick to do this?

Comment: Does your supervisor have pointy hair?

Comment: Yes. Yes, yes, yes. Also, how did you do that?

Comment: turn the image link into an actual image

Comment: Once you have a certain number of reputation points you can do that. Aim high.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what iOS does to select boxes anyway, so just use a select element with some options in it, and it will be fine. Phew!

Comment: One small problem: the select element appears as a normal dropdown list UNTIL CLICKED, at which time the roller style menu slides up into view. Is there a way to make it appear naturally as a roller menu, before the user even touches it?

Comment: Well, guess you could trigger a click with JS, but that would block the rest of the page. Maybe that's OK?

Comment: The only element beneath it is a Submit button. Could you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: If you were using jQuery (because it's short!), something like $("#id_of_select_element").trigger("click"); called on load.